# OpenCV's KNN Unknown Classifications

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, opencv, knn

At the moment I am using OpenCV's KNN implementation to classify images. It currently classifies images into P, S or rectangle, and correctly. However if I feed it an image of noise it will attempt to classify it as 1 of the 3 classifications I stated earlier. To get it to classify as noise, should I train the KNN to put noise in a 'noise' category, or is there some kind of accuracy rating I can use?

Comment: you should do it in regression mode and use the returned value as a "certainty" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is to use the dists variable in the knn_nearest function. It spits out the distance between your vector and the K unit vectors, the further the distance the less they have in common with the test data.

Comment: How would you define a maximum valid distance? Is there an analytical way of finding out when a feature vector is “too far away” from a K unit vector?

Comment: I guess on your test set you could do a binary search to see where the accuracy and recall begin to deteriorate.

Answer (score 0):

yes, but i wouldnt advise it. If you have a classifier which is good at distinguishing between oranges and apples, you shouldn't try making it recognizes "not a fruit". First because you can feed wrong inputs to almost anything, second because it will lower its original performance, and third because you need `noise` to have a pattern. How do you define noise??

Comment: "Noise" is quite well defined in signal processing. _White noise_ has a flat spectrum, and _pink noise_ has a `1/f` spectrum.